# Get a Value from an Angular Factory method

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner Angular developer and am trying to get a value from a method in an Angular factory. I have been struggling with this for awhile and hope someone can help!
Sorry the code is formatted poorly as I copied from a Word document.

My Factory code...

```
driverPortalApp.factory('asideFactory', [
      '$http', '$q', '$rootScope', function ($http, $q, $rootScope) {
          return {
                //This is the function I want to get the value from.
                //It will return a 'true' or 'false' string.    
                getLastCheckboxValue: function () {
                return $http.get('Home/ReadPageLog')
                          .then(function (result) {
                            //this did not work as when I tried to reference it     in the controller I get 'undefined'.
                            $rootScope.doNotShowChecked = result.data;

                          });
              }
          };
      }
  ]);
```

My Controller code...

```
driverPortalApp.controller('asideController', [
     '$scope', '$aside', 'asideFactory', 'asideContent', '$rootScope', '$http', function ($scope, $aside, asideFactory, asideContent, $rootScope, $http) {


    if (asides.length > 0) {

       //I need to get the value from getLastCheckboxValue  here

       doNotShowChecked = asideFactory.getLastCheckboxValue().success(result);

        [0](); //Open the initial pop-over
     }
 ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right in your approach to use factory / service. You'd need to change the way you handle the `promise` though.

The method in service returns a `promise callback`, which assigns a value to `$rootScope.doNotShowChecked` after the `http get` is successful. 
So if you want to access the same in your controller you need to access it in the promise callback, as:

```
asideFactory.getLastCheckboxValue().then(function(result){
 // access $rootScope.doNotShowChecked here
});
```

Or if you return the http result is your promise callback instead of assigning it to the `$rootScope`, as

```
return $http.get('Home/ReadPageLog')
                .then(function (result) {                                
                        return result.data;    
                      });
```

Then it will be available in the promise callback as,

```
asideFactory.getLastCheckboxValue().then(function(doNotShowChecked){
     var returnValue = doNotShowChecked;
    });
```

HTH